# Reading 'CSV' file - Cannot read csv file contains loong string

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I am using following method to read .csv file. It is working fine for csv files which contains normal strings, numbers ect.

But it fails to read csv files contains long strings (eg: description of 5,6 lines).

Is there is such technical difficulty? Your help is highly appreciated.

```
 -(void)readTitleFromCSV:(NSString*)path AtColumn:(int)column
{
//arrBreeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *arrTemp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSString *fileDataString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *linesArray=[fileDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

// preparing array with questions and answers
for(int i=0; i<[linesArray count];i++){
    [arrTemp addObject:[[linesArray objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","] ];
}

 NSLog(@"ArrBreeds %@", arrTemp); 

}
```

Comment: Do your long strings contain commas?

Comment: Yes, but I removed both ";" and "," still not work

Answer (score 0):

You are first separating the text from your CSV file based on line break and then separating the components. This happens something like this:

absd,sgsgs
 dfdf,dfghj

Here you should get 3 objects after parsing , but with your code you will get 4.

You could just go on with this:

```
NSArray *linesArray=[fileDataString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```