# Reading 'CSV' file - Not displayed loong string

Tags: ios, objective-c, csv

My friends, I have an issue that I hope you can help me. 
Here is a similar problem, but it is also not solved:
[Reading 'CSV' file - Cannot read csv file contains loong string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970469/reading-csv-file-cannot-read-csv-file-contains-loong-string)

So...Here is my code:

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"nameorg" ofType:@"csv"];
    NSString* fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSMutableArray* pointStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[fileContents componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]]];

    for(int idx = 0; idx < [pointStrings count]; idx++)
    {

        NSString *currentPointString = [pointStrings objectAtIndex:idx];
        if ([currentPointString length] == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        NSMutableArray *arr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]];
        if ([arr count] < 5) {
            continue;
        }

        NSLog(@"1: %@; 2: %@; 3: %@; 4: %@; 5: %@;", [arr objectAtIndex:0], [arr objectAtIndex:1], [arr objectAtIndex:2], [arr objectAtIndex:3], [arr objectAtIndex:4]);
    }
```

My csv file:

```
2.6.;¬ качестве адреса организации можно использовать адрес офиса учредител€, в том числе домашний адрес руководител€ фирмы, адрес арендованного помещени€.;;The address of administrative office, including home address of the company administrator, the address of  leased premises,  may be used as address of the organization.;
2.7.;Ёлектронна€ подача с помощью сервиса Ђѕодача электронных документов на государственную регистрациюї http://www.nalog.ru/el_usl/gosreg_eldocs/;"1. «аполнить в интерактивном режиме за€вление и направить его в налоговую инспекцию.
2. ѕодготовить полный пакет документов в электронном виде и направить его в налоговый орган.";E-applications submission through the service ЂElectronic submission of documents for state registrationї†http://www.nalog.ru/el_usl/gosreg_eldocs/;"1 . To fill an application online and submit it to tax service.
2 . To prepare a full set of documents in electronic form and send it to tax registration authority."
2.8.;¬ бумажном виде;;In paper form;
```

The problem: Not displayed item 2.7. Why?

My NSLog:

```
2014-02-11 14:03:34.139 CSVSQLITE[4127:70b] 1: 2.6.; 2: В качестве адреса организации можно использовать адрес офиса учредителя, в том числе домашний адрес руководителя фирмы, адрес арендованного помещения.; 3: ; 4: The address of administrative office, including home address of the company administrator, the address of  leased premises,  may be used as address of the organization.; 5: ;
2014-02-11 14:03:34.163 CSVSQLITE[4127:70b] 1: 2.8.; 2: В бумажном виде; 3: ; 4: In paper form; 5: ;
```

Thanks so much in advanced.

output of pointStrings:

```
    (
"2.6.;\U0412 \U043a\U0430\U0447\U0435\U0441\U0442\U0432\U0435 \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441\U0430 \U043e\U0440\U0433\U0430\U043d\U0438\U0437\U0430\U0446\U0438\U0438 \U043c\U043e\U0436\U043d\U043e \U0438\U0441\U043f\U043e\U043b\U044c\U0437\U043e\U0432\U0430\U0442\U044c \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441 \U043e\U0444\U0438\U0441\U0430 \U0443\U0447\U0440\U0435\U0434\U0438\U0442\U0435\U043b\U044f, \U0432 \U0442\U043e\U043c \U0447\U0438\U0441\U043b\U0435 \U0434\U043e\U043c\U0430\U0448\U043d\U0438\U0439 \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441 \U0440\U0443\U043a\U043e\U0432\U043e\U0434\U0438\U0442\U0435\U043b\U044f \U0444\U0438\U0440\U043c\U044b, \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441 \U0430\U0440\U0435\U043d\U0434\U043e\U0432\U0430\U043d\U043d\U043e\U0433\U043e \U043f\U043e\U043c\U0435\U0449\U0435\U043d\U0438\U044f.;;The address of administrative office, including home address of the company administrator, the address of  leased premises,  may be used as address of the organization.;",
    "",
    "2.7.;\U042d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043d\U043d\U0430\U044f \U043f\U043e\U0434\U0430\U0447\U0430 \U0441 \U043f\U043e\U043c\U043e\U0449\U044c\U044e \U0441\U0435\U0440\U0432\U0438\U0441\U0430 \U00ab\U041f\U043e\U0434\U0430\U0447\U0430 \U044d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0445 \U0434\U043e\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0435\U043d\U0442\U043e\U0432 \U043d\U0430 \U0433\U043e\U0441\U0443\U0434\U0430\U0440\U0441\U0442\U0432\U0435\U043d\U043d\U0443\U044e \U0440\U0435\U0433\U0438\U0441\U0442\U0440\U0430\U0446\U0438\U044e\U00bb http://www.nalog.ru/el_usl/gosreg_eldocs/;\"1. \U0417\U0430\U043f\U043e\U043b\U043d\U0438\U0442\U044c \U0432 \U0438\U043d\U0442\U0435\U0440\U0430\U043a\U0442\U0438\U0432\U043d\U043e\U043c \U0440\U0435\U0436\U0438\U043c\U0435 \U0437\U0430\U044f\U0432\U043b\U0435\U043d\U0438\U0435 \U0438 \U043d\U0430\U043f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0438\U0442\U044c \U0435\U0433\U043e \U0432 \U043d\U0430\U043b\U043e\U0433\U043e\U0432\U0443\U044e \U0438\U043d\U0441\U043f\U0435\U043a\U0446\U0438\U044e.",
    "2. \U041f\U043e\U0434\U0433\U043e\U0442\U043e\U0432\U0438\U0442\U044c \U043f\U043e\U043b\U043d\U044b\U0439 \U043f\U0430\U043a\U0435\U0442 \U0434\U043e\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0435\U043d\U0442\U043e\U0432 \U0432 \U044d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043d\U043d\U043e\U043c \U0432\U0438\U0434\U0435 \U0438 \U043d\U0430\U043f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0438\U0442\U044c \U0435\U0433\U043e \U0432 \U043d\U0430\U043b\U043e\U0433\U043e\U0432\U044b\U0439 \U043e\U0440\U0433\U0430\U043d.\";E-applications submission through the service \U00abElectronic submission of documents for state registration\U00bb\U00a0http://www.nalog.ru/el_usl/gosreg_eldocs/;\"1 . To fill an application online and submit it to tax service.",
    "",
    "2 . To prepare a full set of documents in electronic form and send it to tax registration authority.\"",
    "",
    "2.8.;\U0412 \U0431\U0443\U043c\U0430\U0436\U043d\U043e\U043c \U0432\U0438\U0434\U0435;;In paper form;",
    "",
    )
```

output of arr:

```
2014-02-11 14:07:58.545 CSVSQLITE[4249:70b] arr: (
    "2.6.",
    "\U0412 \U043a\U0430\U0447\U0435\U0441\U0442\U0432\U0435 \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441\U0430 \U043e\U0440\U0433\U0430\U043d\U0438\U0437\U0430\U0446\U0438\U0438 \U043c\U043e\U0436\U043d\U043e \U0438\U0441\U043f\U043e\U043b\U044c\U0437\U043e\U0432\U0430\U0442\U044c \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441 \U043e\U0444\U0438\U0441\U0430 \U0443\U0447\U0440\U0435\U0434\U0438\U0442\U0435\U043b\U044f, \U0432 \U0442\U043e\U043c \U0447\U0438\U0441\U043b\U0435 \U0434\U043e\U043c\U0430\U0448\U043d\U0438\U0439 \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441 \U0440\U0443\U043a\U043e\U0432\U043e\U0434\U0438\U0442\U0435\U043b\U044f \U0444\U0438\U0440\U043c\U044b, \U0430\U0434\U0440\U0435\U0441 \U0430\U0440\U0435\U043d\U0434\U043e\U0432\U0430\U043d\U043d\U043e\U0433\U043e \U043f\U043e\U043c\U0435\U0449\U0435\U043d\U0438\U044f.",
    "",
    "The address of administrative office, including home address of the company administrator, the address of  leased premises,  may be used as address of the organization.",
    ""
)
2014-02-11 14:07:58.548 CSVSQLITE[4249:70b] arr: (
    "2.7.",
    "\U042d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043d\U043d\U0430\U044f \U043f\U043e\U0434\U0430\U0447\U0430 \U0441 \U043f\U043e\U043c\U043e\U0449\U044c\U044e \U0441\U0435\U0440\U0432\U0438\U0441\U0430 \U00ab\U041f\U043e\U0434\U0430\U0447\U0430 \U044d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0445 \U0434\U043e\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0435\U043d\U0442\U043e\U0432 \U043d\U0430 \U0433\U043e\U0441\U0443\U0434\U0430\U0440\U0441\U0442\U0432\U0435\U043d\U043d\U0443\U044e \U0440\U0435\U0433\U0438\U0441\U0442\U0440\U0430\U0446\U0438\U044e\U00bb http://www.nalog.ru/el_usl/gosreg_eldocs/",
    "\"1. \U0417\U0430\U043f\U043e\U043b\U043d\U0438\U0442\U044c \U0432 \U0438\U043d\U0442\U0435\U0440\U0430\U043a\U0442\U0438\U0432\U043d\U043e\U043c \U0440\U0435\U0436\U0438\U043c\U0435 \U0437\U0430\U044f\U0432\U043b\U0435\U043d\U0438\U0435 \U0438 \U043d\U0430\U043f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0438\U0442\U044c \U0435\U0433\U043e \U0432 \U043d\U0430\U043b\U043e\U0433\U043e\U0432\U0443\U044e \U0438\U043d\U0441\U043f\U0435\U043a\U0446\U0438\U044e."
)
2014-02-11 14:07:58.549 CSVSQLITE[4249:70b] arr: (
    "2. \U041f\U043e\U0434\U0433\U043e\U0442\U043e\U0432\U0438\U0442\U044c \U043f\U043e\U043b\U043d\U044b\U0439 \U043f\U0430\U043a\U0435\U0442 \U0434\U043e\U043a\U0443\U043c\U0435\U043d\U0442\U043e\U0432 \U0432 \U044d\U043b\U0435\U043a\U0442\U0440\U043e\U043d\U043d\U043e\U043c \U0432\U0438\U0434\U0435 \U0438 \U043d\U0430\U043f\U0440\U0430\U0432\U0438\U0442\U044c \U0435\U0433\U043e \U0432 \U043d\U0430\U043b\U043e\U0433\U043e\U0432\U044b\U0439 \U043e\U0440\U0433\U0430\U043d.\"",
    "E-applications submission through the service \U00abElectronic submission of documents for state registration\U00bb\U00a0http://www.nalog.ru/el_usl/gosreg_eldocs/",
    "\"1 . To fill an application online and submit it to tax service."
)
2014-02-11 14:07:58.550 CSVSQLITE[4249:70b] arr: (
    "2 . To prepare a full set of documents in electronic form and send it to tax registration authority.\""
)
2014-02-11 14:07:58.551 CSVSQLITE[4249:70b] arr: (
    "2.8.",
    "\U0412 \U0431\U0443\U043c\U0430\U0436\U043d\U043e\U043c \U0432\U0438\U0434\U0435",
    "",
    "In paper form",
    ""
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2.7 is not displaying because of the following if condition.

```
if ([arr count] < 5)
{
    continue;
}
```

The 2.7 String contains only two `;`

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [currentPointString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]];
```

It'll contain only 3 objects, so the if condition is satisfied.

Comment: @user3296314: You need to remove that continue statement and use an loop for printing the content of that array.

Comment: Work! Thanks Midhun MP)))))